# HTML Export to Excel using JavaScript ,WORKING IN FIREFOX but NOT IN IE & CHROME

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, export, export-to-excel

I have a database generated table using PHP .

For exporting the table , I am using the following code to save its contents in .xls format.

Previously this script was working fine in Chrome , but now it has stopped ...when I click the button then a window opens but NO FILE GETS DOWNLOADED.....?

**BUT IN FIREFOX it works**

What may be the problem in Chrome ? How do I find out that problem , is there any tool to find out the script problem in Chrome?

Please help.

```
$( "#Export" ).click(function() {  
    var Contents = $('#MyTable').html();    
    alert(''+Contents);
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel, ' +  '<table>'+encodeURIComponent($('#MyTable').html()) +  '</table>' );
    alert('exporting records...');
});
```

In Chrome , both the Message boxes are also displayed, but no file gets saved on my PC.
It was previously working without any problem but I don't know why it has stopped now.

Comment: Derek : sir , it was working fine and great but today when i tested it , its not working. I can't find out the problem....Both the alert boxes are shown properly also , one shows the HTML of the table and the other shows this message : 'exporting records' , and even the window also opens but no file gets downloaded ....am stuck up here

Comment: Did you try right-click on the window (I mean the popup), then press "Save as"?

Comment: But Save As would save more things which I have on the page , like have many divisions also

Comment: Can anybody find out the problem in the script

Comment: See if this helps you. http://slides.html5rocks.com/#drag-out

Comment: is there no solution to this problem?

Comment: ITS WORKING IN MOZILLA FIREFOX  , BUT NOT IN CHROME AND IE

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11498/discussion-between-sqlchild-and-derek)

Comment: You need to relax.

Comment: @BoltClock : can't sir , its very urgent for me to solve it , need an immediate solution to this problem . very worried

Comment: @BoltClock : please can singapore's top user help me ?

Comment: @sqlchild You may put a bounty on the question, that attracts the attention of the community.

Comment: @AurA: He can't do that until 2 days later. Bountying won't be helpful here since, you know, it's urgent and all.

Comment: @BoltClock  : if its working in FIREFOX then what could be problem in CHROME?

Comment: So in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/3783732 you are telling me, there is more code than that snippet you posted. I am certainly not going to debug your script for you. I have given you a means to debug it yourself. I suggest you go do that or else seek a paid professional. Next time please remember, you have to show some effort yourself.

Comment: no sir , i din't mean that...i just that i will paste the code on pastebin or jsfiddle and show you the demo ...that's it....i din't meant wrong but still my apologies for anything which you did not like

Comment: everything is always urgent...that's what you get told so you work harder! like a workhorse! =)