# Exporting a HTML table to Excel. User has to be able to choose name for the file

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, excel, html-table

Im exporting a html table to excel and its works fine, but I want the user to be able to choose name for the file they are downloading.

Here is how I export it:

```
 function exportToExcel() {
 window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' +
 encodeURIComponent($('#exportToExcelDiv').html()));
 e.preventDefault();
 }
```

And here is the link that uses that function:

```
<a href="#" title="Save"><img src="../../Images/glyphicons_446_floppy_save.png"
 alt="save" onclick="exportToExcel()"></a>
```

Is there a way to do this? Its okay not to use javascript. 
(I'm doing a webapplication in MVC4).

Comment: you can set the default filename. but the pop up ask user to choose where/what name to save is depend on the browser setting on the user's pc, something like "Ask where to save each file before downloading" in chrome setting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Export HTML table to Excel JavaScript function add select file name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084232/export-html-table-to-excel-javascript-function-add-select-file-name)

Answer (score 0):

When sending the file to the browser, add a `Content-Disposition` header. In there, you can specify the file name.

Related questions:

- [Export HTML table to Excel JavaScript function add select file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084232/export-html-table-to-excel-javascript-function-add-select-file-name)
- [How to encode the filename parameter of Content-Disposition header in HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http)